# SQL query to join part of table on it's self in TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, timescaledb

I have the following table in TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.data
(
    event_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    pair_id integer NOT NULL,
    ev_data1 int NOT NULL,
    ev_data2 int NOT NULL
)
```

I have ca. 4000 different pair_id's and would like to write a query which gives the following output:

| event_time | pair_id1_ev_data1 | pair_id1_ev_data2 | pair_id2_ev_data1 | pair_id2_ev_data2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

How can I accomplish this efficiently? Is this even possible in postgres? how about in pl/pgsql? It feels like I should be somehow joining the table on it's self but I don't understand how...

Comment: Do you actually want all 4000 of them? Or just some subset, because your options in each case are a bit different...

Comment: @davidk I need to run both types of queries - sometimes just a set of maybe 4-5, sometimes 100, sometimes all 4000